# Is there an easier/more efficient way to make Visible = False for multiple buttons in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

not sure if there is an easier way to do this but I have a LOT of buttons on a form. Different ones are visible for different functions.

Is there a way to have something like this have an easier way to change their visibility without having each button coded to go False/True?

For simplicity sake, I created a quick app to handle the visibility but I want to hide the others when one set of buttons is visible. So if I select Row 1, it will make Visibility FALSE on Row 2 and 3.

Am I stuck with this or is there an easier way/more efficient way? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Button Row 1" Then
            Button1.Visible = True
            Button2.Visible = True
            Button3.Visible = True
            Button4.Visible = True
            Button5.Visible = True
            Button6.Visible = True
            Button7.Visible = True
            Button8.Visible = True
            Button9.Visible = True
            Button10.Visible = True
            Button11.Visible = False
            Button12.Visible = False
            Button13.Visible = False
            Button14.Visible = False
            Button15.Visible = False
            Button16.Visible = False
            Button17.Visible = False
            Button18.Visible = False
            Button19.Visible = False
            Button20.Visible = False
            Button21.Visible = False
            Button22.Visible = False
            Button23.Visible = False
            Button24.Visible = False
            Button25.Visible = False
            Button26.Visible = False
            Button27.Visible = False
            Button28.Visible = False
            Button29.Visible = False
            Button30.Visible = False
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Button Row 2" Then
            Button1.Visible = False
            Button2.Visible = False
            Button3.Visible = False
            Button4.Visible = False
            Button5.Visible = False
            Button6.Visible = False
            Button7.Visible = False
            Button8.Visible = False
            Button9.Visible = False
            Button10.Visible = False
            Button11.Visible = True
            Button12.Visible = True
            Button13.Visible = True
            Button14.Visible = True
            Button15.Visible = True
            Button16.Visible = True
            Button17.Visible = True
            Button18.Visible = True
            Button19.Visible = True
            Button20.Visible = True
            Button21.Visible = False
            Button22.Visible = False
            Button23.Visible = False
            Button24.Visible = False
            Button25.Visible = False
            Button26.Visible = False
            Button27.Visible = False
            Button28.Visible = False
            Button29.Visible = False
            Button30.Visible = False
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Button Row 3" Then
            Button1.Visible = False
            Button2.Visible = False
            Button3.Visible = False
            Button4.Visible = False
            Button5.Visible = False
            Button6.Visible = False
            Button7.Visible = False
            Button8.Visible = False
            Button9.Visible = False
            Button10.Visible = False
            Button11.Visible = False
            Button12.Visible = False
            Button13.Visible = False
            Button14.Visible = False
            Button15.Visible = False
            Button16.Visible = False
            Button17.Visible = False
            Button18.Visible = False
            Button19.Visible = False
            Button20.Visible = False
            Button21.Visible = True
            Button22.Visible = True
            Button23.Visible = True
            Button24.Visible = True
            Button25.Visible = True
            Button26.Visible = True
            Button27.Visible = True
            Button28.Visible = True
            Button29.Visible = True
            Button30.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use only one set of buttons and let them act on the selected row.

Comment: You could put the buttons in a panel per row, then show/hide the panel

Comment: If the controls are related and/or close to each other, put them in a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel) and set the `Visible` property of the Panel to False/True. That said, please note that it's a **terrible** idea to name your controls (Label1, Button1, etc.), let alone when you have that number of controls. You'll lose your mind :)

Comment: Using panel makes more sense.

Comment: I am testing the panel theory now.

Comment: Panel works. I 1 upped your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the tag property of the buttons. You can do it in the properties window. I just show it in code to illustrate the point

```
Button1.Tag = "Button Row 1"
```

Then you can do

```
Dim selectedRow = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
For Each c As Control In Controls
    If (TypeOf c Is Button) Then
        c.Visible = selectedRow.Equals(c.Tag)
    End If
Next
```

Note that this automatically shows the buttons of the selected row and hides the others.

If this affects too many buttons, you can also check if the `Tag` is not `Nothing` instead of testing if it is a button.

Comment: The code only works for the first row of buttons. (Button Row 1). And I had to change the c.Enabled to c.Visible. On the right track though.

Comment: It works for all the row if you set the tags accordingly" `"Button Row 1"`, `"Button Row 2"`, `"Button Row 3"` ...

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I had a typo in the tag field. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use a for loop and keep track of which textbox is in which row, could put the row in the name, tag, use a custom property, etc.
2. You could put each row in a groupbox and just change the visibility of the group.
3. You could make a list of Buttons for each row, add the buttons, and loop through those lists.

Answer (score 1):

Winforms support data binding.

```
' In form constructor
public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent() 

    cmbEnableButtons.DataSource = New List(Of string) From 
    { 
        "Nothing", 
        "Button Row 1", 
        "Button row 2" 
    }
    button1.Tag = "Button Row 1"
    button2.Tag = "Button Row 1"
    button3.Tag = "Button Row 2"
    button4.Tag = "Button Row 2"

    button1.DataBindings.Add(CreateBindingForVisible())
    button2.DataBindings.Add(CreateBindingForVisible())
    button3.DataBindings.Add(CreateBindingForVisible())
    button4.DataBindings.Add(CreateBindingForVisible())
}

Private Function CreateBindingForVisible() As Binding
    Dim buttonBinding = 
        New Binding("Visible", 
                     cmbEnableButtons, 
                     "SelectedValue", 
                     true, 
                     DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)

    ' Every time selected value of combobox changed
    ' this event handler convert string to "visible" boolean
    AddHandler buttonBinding.Format, AddressOf ButtonBinding_Format

    return buttonBinding;
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonBinding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    Dim binding = DirectCast(sender, Binding)
    Dim button = DirectCast(binding.Control, Button)

    e.Value = Equals(button.Tag, e.Value)
End Sub
```

With data binding you can configure every button separately from each other, while having common logic in one place.